# Getting invalid provider error with Capacitor CallNumber

Tags: ionic-framework, phone-call

I am implementing CallNumber.
If I follow the [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/call-number) there is no mention of including the CallNumber in provider so an error s thrown:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError:
> R3InjectorError(HomePageModule)[CallNumber -> CallNumber -> CallNumber
> -> CallNumber]: NullInjectorError: No provider for CallNumber!

So I add CallNumber as a provider in app.module.ts

```
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, StudentModalPage],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
  ],
  providers: [
   CallNumber,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
   
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (platformId: object, response: any) => {
        return () => {
          // In the server.ts we added a custom response header with information about the device requesting the app
          if (isPlatformServer(platformId)) {
            if (response && response !== null) {
              // Get custom header from the response sent from the server.ts
              const mobileDeviceHeader = response.get('mobile-device');

              // Set Ionic config mode?
            }
          }
        };
      },
      deps: [PLATFORM_ID, [new Optional(), RESPONSE]],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
```

But now i get this error:

> Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule' - only instances
> of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?[object Object]?, ..., ...]

I have searched around allot and can't find a solution nor do I underhand the error, any input appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63893581/ionic-5-cordova-plugin-emailcomposer-nullinjectorerror) solution to a similar problem, and changed my import from the automatic import created once I added the provider:

```
 { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';
```

to:

```
{ CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you found how to fix it. Just to add some more context the import you were using is for Ionic 2/3 (in the docs mentioned in the OP the import is `@ionic-native/call-number/ngx` which is the correct one). So yeah, this is a very common issue specially when migrating an Ionic 3 app to Ionic 4/5 :)

Comment: Thanks - what threw me was when I added the provider the import was automatically added, but the incorrect import was added, why would this be?